# Remove a className only the sam parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

do you know how to keep selected a div in a different column, right every time I click on a div it remove the previous selected. I would like to keep the user choice selected on each different column : [https://codepen.io/dodgpine/pen/bGaqWVG][1]

```js
const subTitleBuild = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-title-build");
const subTitleOs = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-title-os");
const subTitlePackage = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-title-package");
const subTitleLanguage = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-title-language");
const subTitleCuda = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-title-cuda");

const selections = [
  subTitleBuild,
  subTitleOs,
  subTitlePackage,
  subTitleLanguage,
  subTitleCuda,
];

selections.forEach((selection) => {
  selection.forEach((title) => {
    title.addEventListener("click", () => {
      removeSelectedClasses();
      title.classList.add("selected");
    });
  });
});

function removeSelectedClasses() {
  selections.forEach((selection) => {
    selection.forEach((title) => {
      console.log(title);
      title.classList.remove("selected");
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made two changes to your javascript, which I think achieve what you want (if I have understood correctly, you want a click to apply the class `selected` without affecting previously selected options, and, presumably, be able to remove earlier selections with another click on them).

Firstly, I commented out (removed) `title.classList.remove("selected");` from your `removeSelectedClasses()` function, as this is what was clearing earlier selections.

Secondly, I modified, `title.classList.add("selected");` in your event listeners to instead toggle the `selected` class on and off using: `title.classList.toggle("selected");`. This enables a single click to apply the `selected` class, while a second click on the same box removes it.

The snippet below works to show the effect.

I note you probably need column selections to be limited to a single choice, so you will have to fiddle with how the changes I suggested are applied. But the principle should help you do that.

```js
const subTitleBuild = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-title-build");
const subTitleOs = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-title-os");
const subTitlePackage = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-title-package");
const subTitleLanguage = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-title-language");
const subTitleCuda = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-title-cuda");

const selections = [
  subTitleBuild,
  subTitleOs,
  subTitlePackage,
  subTitleLanguage,
  subTitleCuda,
];

selections.forEach((selection) => {
  selection.forEach((title) => {
    title.addEventListener("click", () => {
      removeSelectedClasses();
      title.classList.toggle("selected");
    });
  });
});

function removeSelectedClasses() {
  selections.forEach((selection) => {
    selection.forEach((title) => {
      console.log(title);
      //title.classList.remove("selected");
      
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.container-master {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;

  justify-content: space-between;
}

.column {
  width: 170px;
}

.container-btn {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.title {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: #3e4652;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.sub-title,
.sub-title-build {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row-cmd {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.container-btn-cmd {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.command-container {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: orangered;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container-master">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="column ptbuild">
          <div class="container-btn title">
            <div class="btn">PyTorch Build</div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-btn sub-title-build" id="stable">
            <div class="btn">Stable (1.11.0)</div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-btn sub-title-build" id="preview">
            <div class="btn">Preview (Nightly)</div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-btn sub-title-build" id="lts">
            <div class="btn">LTS (1.8.2)</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column os">
          <div class="container-btn title">
            <div class="btn">Your OS</div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-btn sub-title-os" id="linux">
            <div class="btn">Linux</div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-btn sub-title-os" id="macos">
            <div class="btn">Mac</div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-btn sub-title-os" id="windows">
            <div class="btn">Windows</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column package">
          <div class="container-btn title">
            <div class="btn">Package</div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-btn sub-title-package" id="conda">
            <div class="btn">Conda</div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-btn sub-title-package" id="pip">
            <div class="btn">Pip</div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-btn sub-title-package" id="libtorch">
            <div class="btn">LibTorch</div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-btn sub-title-package" id="source">
            <div class="btn">Source</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column language">
          <div class="container-btn title">
            <div class="btn">Language</div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-btn sub-title-language" id="python">
            <div class="btn">Python</div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-btn sub-title-language" id="cplusplus">
            <div class="btn">C++ / Java</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column cuda">
          <div class="container-btn title">
            <div class="btn">Compute Platform</div>
          </div>
          <div
            class="container-btn sub-title-cuda"
            id="cuda10.2"
            style="text-decoration: line-through"
          >
            <div class="btn">CUDA 10.2</div>
          </div>
          <div
            class="container-btn sub-title-cuda"
            id="cuda11.x"
            style="text-decoration: line-through"
          >
            <div class="btn">CUDA 11.3</div>
          </div>
          <div
            class="container-btn sub-title-cuda"
            id="rocm4.x"
            style="text-decoration: line-through"
          >
            <div class="btn">ROCM 4.2 (beta)</div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-btn sub-title-cuda" id="accnone">
            <div class="btn">CPU</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row-cmd">
        <div class="container-btn-cmd title">
          <div class="option-text">Run this Command:</div>
        </div>
        <div class="command-container">
          <div class="cmd-text" id="command">
            <pre># MacOS Binaries dont support CUDA, install from source if CUDA is needed<br>conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio -c pytorch</pre>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Dave for your quick reply, it's getting there however I would like to the user to be able to change his choice in each column without affecting the other one. I know if quit difficult to explain however Im trying to redisign this selection choice : https://pytorch.org/

Comment: @pytorch.org yes, I understand now I think. I've been having a play but not quite there yet. The approach I'm trying is to identify the parent container for the clicked item (the column) and first clearing the selected style from each child (of that column only) before toggling the selected style. I'm just working out the layers of class names. Will modify my answer if I make any progress.

Comment: just found the solution : https://codepen.io/dodgpine/pen/eYyvWQV       just needed to pass a param to the remove function

Comment: great. I'd been trying similar but was having trouble navigating up and down parent elements to limit changes to the column containing the clicked button.

Comment: Thank a lot for your help anyway, see you on the next problem ;)